# How do I implement Div inside Div using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have one div with id and I want to implement 4 divs inside it and also 5 divs for each. The code I have worked with is below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        j=i+1;
        document.getElementById("king").innerHTML += "<div id='level"+" "+"level--"+j+"'"+"></div>";
        var mainClass = "level--"+j;
        for(k=0;k<5;k++){
            console.log(mainClass);
            document.getElementById(mainClass).innerHTML += "<div></div>";
        }
    }
});
```

By the way each div is having different id so corresponding to that id I want to implement the div so I have used the mainClass variable.

The plunker to this is https://plnkr.co/edit/mbcRhnMLsCXDnLhndVQB?p=catalogue.

Comment: 1. Click the `<>` and post the code here. 2. FIX the code so it does not give errors. Your plunkr does not work - you call the script main but load script.js 3. you cannot access anything with  "level--"+j; unless it exists in the DOM 4 do NOT mix jQuery and DOM access it is very messy

Comment: Note: You can't have spaces in identifier

Comment: I have updated my plunker but still its the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the <> and post the code here.
2. FIX the code so it does not give errors. Your plunkr does not work - you call the script main but load script.js
3. you cannot access anything with "level--"+j; unless it exists in the DOM
4. do NOT mix jQuery and DOM access it is very messy

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    id = "level--" + (i + 1);
    $("#king").append("<div id='" + id + "'>"+id+"</div>");
    var $mainclass = $("#" + id);
    for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      $mainclass.append("<div>"+k+"</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="king"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but what you think about jquery [.prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) functions something like this

```
$('mainClass').prepend($('<div> new div </div>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code based on my and you will get it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var king = $('#king');
  
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var j = i + 1;
    var node = document.createElement('li');
    node.innerText = "Parent" + j;
    king.append(node);
    for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      var nodeChild = document.createElement('li');
      nodeChild.innerText = "Child" + k;
      node.append(nodeChild);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="king"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with jQuery might work

```js
// Code goes here

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var king = $("#king");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
  var div = $("<div class='external'>external div:" + i + "</div>");
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
      div.append("<div class='internal'>internal div:" + j +"</div>");
    }
    king.append(div);
 }
});
```

```css
 .external{
    background-color: lightblue;
 }
 
 .internal{
    background-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Apple</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="king"></div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```